# How to get a Object from inputs in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, object, input

For exemple, i have 3 inputs

```
<input type="text" name="color" value="blue"/>
<input type="text" name="flavor" value="acid"/>
<input type="text" name="name" value="jack"/>
```

And a i need get something like this

```
const obj = {color:'blue', flavor:'acid', name:'jack};
```

I tried use a for loop, but i get a array, not a object

```
var obj = [];
var x = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  obj.push(x[i].value)
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the values using a `forEach` and update the object.
Note: Could also use `reduce` to directly create the object

```js
const obj = {};
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
 obj[name] = value
})

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="color" value="blue" />
<input type="text" name="flavor" value="acid" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="jack" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript [object](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_objects.asp) instead of an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). To create a object key you just have to declare it between the brackets [ ] and assign a value.

```js
var obj = {};
var x = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  obj[x[i].name] = x[i].value
}
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="color" value="blue"/>
<input type="text" name="flavor" value="acid"/>
<input type="text" name="name" value="jack"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JavaScript object with dynamic property names:

```js
var obj = {};
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => obj[input.name] = input.value);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="color" value="blue" />
<input type="text" name="flavor" value="acid" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="jack" />
```

Comment: What is the difference in relation with the other answers?

Comment: I will change it @Lolpez.